# How can i make Dynamics CRM users not seeing records of each other?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

We have an CRM 2015 Organization and we want to give access to our users the way that not seeing or interacting of records of each other, like they feel they are alone.
We want to avoid creating organization database for each user because of limited hardware resources.
Also better to mention that they can work and do their business with just one user in organization.
First thing that came into my mind was using permissions, but don't know exactly how to define and arrange this permissions.
Or maybe there is a better way that i don't know of.
Please let me know, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Security Roles is the right approach.

To prevent users from seeing records created by other users, change their permissions to only allow **User** *Read* permissions:

[image: CRM Security Role Key]

You will need to create a new Security Role (or modify an existing one) and configure the permissions for each Entity.

Note that some entities are **Organization** owned; for these entities, you can only toggle between the **Organization** access (full green circle) or no access (empty red circle).

Some entities are required by the system to work so you will need to provide Read permissions (e.g. Currency) so you have to be very careful when creating your role.

Also remember that if a user has multiple security roles assigned, then they will be given the highest permission. For example

- Role 1: Account Read: Organization
- Role 2: Account Read: User

  = User will have Organization Read for Accounts

Comment: Iv'e done this approach and its complicated and very error prone and easily gives me Access Denied. Instead of User level i used BU level and all those which needed Organization level i left it Organization(I created a Business Unit per user). And for entities like Product i edited its builtin views and added CreatedBy equals current user filter, and denied creating or editing views for all entities, and by doing all of this i got my desired result.

Comment: @JalaliShakib yes, this is a technically difficult thing to complete because of all the depenencies. Depending on the size of your CRM system, and the eventual reporting needs, creating a BU per user is not something I would normally recommend. It also sets up a lot of behind the scenes objects (teams, queues, etc.) that exist per BU

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Security Role for your problem. Everything Is Simple.[See This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPNIA.jpg)

There Is two notice for using Security Role. First check your Entity Ownership And Second Complete the rules.
If you Use Ownership with organization Value your rules only can switch between two state (none & Organization) but If your Ownership value is user or team you can switch your rule between five state.

In Rule Page you Have eight Condition and five state for each entity.

**None** State : It means Nothing access in any condition on That Entity.

**User** State : It means You can access Only to Records that Owns by you on That Entity.

**Business Unit** State :It Means You Can Access any record that is Under Your Business Unit on That Entity

**Parent: Child Business Units** :It means If you are in a business unit that have child , Then You Can access records is under your business unit and your business unit child's on That Entity

**Organization** : It Means You can Access Any Thing in any where on That Entity.

I Hope it Can Help You.

Answer (score -1):

The better way is using the Security roles.

Go to the security roles is associate to the users, open and go to separator "Business Management" and the place is of the entity user on circle of read put in none and is done. This is the better way to they can't see anything about the users.

You can see on this image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6vBI.png.

Cheers,
Jorge Cunha

Comment: I test it out and if i empty that permission CRM showing me Access Denied error message. I used copy of Salesperson Security Role.

Comment: I don't think the OP was referring to permissions for the User entity, rather that each User should not be able to see records created by other users